# Thesis in the Netherlands

Tags: netherlands, indian-citizens, study

I am from India. I am currently studying for a Master's in Germany. I will be doing my Master's thesis in the Netherlands for around 5 months.

Do I need a work permit to do my thesis in the Netherlands? What other things are required?

Comment: Whether you need a work permit depends on exactly what is meant by "do your thesis."  Does it include being employed in the Netherlands?  In any event you will need a lung-stay visa or a residence permit; your German document permits you to stay in other Schengen countries only up to 90 days in any 180-day period.

Answer (score 1):

From the [StudyInHolland site, section Visas and permits](https://www.studyinholland.nl/practical-matters/visas-and-permits):

> Whether you need a visa or not, depends on:
>   - your nationality – as stated on your passport;
>   - the duration of your stay: shorter or longer than 90 days;
>   - your purpose of stay.
>   Your institution needs to apply
>   When you enrol in a study programme, your host institution will contact you to start up the application procedure. If not, ask for help by contacting contacting the international office (or if you are a researcher, the HR department) of your host institution.

They have a [PathFinder tool](https://www.studyinholland.nl/practical-matters/get-prepared) where you can fill in your information. This will tell you e.g. (from the *Residence permit for study (TEV)*):

> Conditions
>   There are certain conditions that apply to everyone. In addition, you and your educational institution have to meet the following conditions:
>   - You have (provisionally) been accepted by a university or university of applied sciences as a student to a full-time accredited day programme. This university or university of applied sciences is a recognised sponsor. Recognised educational institutions are listed in the Public Register of Recognised Sponsors.
>   - Your must have sufficient independent long-term funds. There are various ways to show this.
>   - You obtain at least 50% of the required credits for each academic year. This is called study progress monitoring.

And:

> Do you have your bachelor's degree and you are going to continue a master's programme? It is then possible to again make use of a maximum of 12 months to prepare for your master's programme.
>   Your educational institution determines the conditions of your education.

And:

> The educational institution has a list of documents that you need. You have to have official foreign documents legalised and translated into Dutch, English, French or German

Also, from the *Work permit for a part-time job* document:

> As an international student in the Netherlands, you may want to work alongside your studies or internship. If so, there are some restrictions you will need to take into account.
>   If you have a residence permit for the purposes of study, the number of hours you are allowed to work is restricted. You may either work full-time in June, July and August only, or work part-time (at most ten hours a week) throughout the rest of the year. You are not allowed to do both. Furthermore, your employer or employment agency has to give you a competitive salary and terms of employment.
>   If you are not a citizen of an EU/EEA country or are a citizen of Croatia, you will need a work permit, which is issued for a maximum duration of one year. It is up to your employer or employment agency to apply for a work permit from the UWV Employee Insurance Agency on your behalf. You cannot do this yourself. The work permit application must be accompanied by a copy of your residence permit for study purposes and a statement from your education institution confirming that you are enrolled as a student at that institution. If you are a citizen of an EU-EEA country, you are allowed to work in the Netherlands, a work permit is not necessary.

So, I suggest contacting the institute where you are going to your thesis, they will know best.